# FMOD no sound in unity at all

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, fmod

When trying to play fmod events in unity (not even via script) I don't hear anything. I've tried a couple of things. I've tried making a new project (both for unity and fmod) without any results, I've also added FMOD_DEBUG to the scripting define symbols. It doesn't give an error. I really don't know what to do here and I really need this to work.

Here is the editor.log after trying to test playing an event (via code):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/14z232whn26z273/Editor.log?dl=0 (there were too many characters to directly include it here)

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you delete the 3D panner in the Master track of your events. You might not hear the sound because it's too far from the listener. Also make sure you've put the fmod listener script on your main camera.